# pandas groupby で集計を行った列の列名

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'生物':['しろくま','ねこ','うさぎ','ラッコ','モモンガ','シーサー','オデ','鎧金','鎧銀'],
                    'カテゴリ':['戦闘員','戦闘員','戦闘員','戦闘員','戦闘員','戦闘員','外部有識者','管理者','管理者'],
                    'HP':[2,50,100,600,60,72,1000,1000,1000]})
df1
```

度々失礼します。
pandas.dataFrameにおいて、集計した際の列名について質問させてください。
上記のような df1 に対して、以下のように集計を行った場合の df2 の列名ですが、

```
df2 = df1[['カテゴリ','HP']].groupby('カテゴリ').mean()
df2.dtypes
```

df2.dtypesを実行すると、結果にカテゴリ列が表示されず、HP列のみが表示されているのはなぜでしょうか。
df2の結果を使って、グラフ表示を行いたいのですが、x軸に設定しようと考えているカテゴリ列を参照すると、エラーになってしまいます。

基本的な内容の質問で大変恐縮ですが、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `as_index=False` を指定してもよいでしょう。`df1[['カテゴリ','HP']].groupby('カテゴリ', as_index=False).mean()`

Answer (score 1):

`.groupby('カテゴリ')` によって指定列がインデックスになったためです。

```py
df3 = df2.reset_index()   # インデックスを外した df2

df2.reset_index().dtypes   # dtypes
```

また, plotするなら `df2.index` の値を使うと可能

---

##### (追記) 検証

```py
In [2]: df2 = df1[['カテゴリ','HP']].groupby('カテゴリ').mean()

In [3]: df2.dtypes
Out[3]:
HP    float64
dtype: object

In [4]: df2.columns
Out[4]: Index(['HP'], dtype='object')

In [5]: df2.index
Out[5]: Index(['外部有識者', '戦闘員', '管理者'], dtype='object', name='カテゴリ')

In [6]: df2.reset_index().dtypes
Out[6]:
カテゴリ     object
HP      float64
dtype: object

In [7]: df3 = df2.reset_index()

In [8]: df3.columns
Out[8]: Index(['カテゴリ', 'HP'], dtype='object')
```